# How can I make this Java program run faster?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am solving [this problem from HackerEarth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/practice-problems/algorithm/moody-numbers/) but I am getting the "Time limit exceeded" error.

> Function F(N) is defined as:
>
> F(N) = sum_of_digits(N<sup>2</sup>)
>
> Given a number N, output if it is possible for it to ultimately become {1 or 4} or not.
>
> Input:
> First line contains T which is the number of test cases.
> T lines follow each with an integer N.
>
> Output:
> For each N output "YES" or "NO" if the number can achieve desired goal or not.

This is the program:

```java
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MoodyNumbers {

    public static boolean is1or4(int x) {
        boolean result = false;
        Integer digitSum = Stream.of((int) Math.pow(x, 2)).reduce(Integer::sum).get();
        StringBuilder sumStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(digitSum));
        for (int i = 0; i < sumStringBuilder.length(); i++) {
            result = sumStringBuilder.charAt(i) == '1' || sumStringBuilder.charAt(i) == '4';
            if (result) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(System.out);
        int numberOfTest = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTest; i++) {
            boolean result = is1or4(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));
            if (result) {
                bos.write("YES\n".getBytes());
            }
            else {
                bos.write("NO\n".getBytes());
            }
            bos.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

I ran out of ideas to make this faster, any recommendations?

Comment: `Stream.of(someInt)` __does not__ give you a stream of its _digits_. Your code isn't slow; it's broken.

Comment: If it's achieving a Time Limit Exceeded, it's probably slow. It's definitely broken, but that doesn't stop it being slow.

Comment: There is no sense in wrapping `System.out` in a `BufferedOutputStream`, especially not when you’re call `flush()` after every line anyway. Just use `System.out.println("YES");` and `System.out.println("NO");` or replace the entire `if` statement with `System.out.println(result? "YES": "NO");` The first comment already mentioned that you’re not calculating a digit sum at all. What you further didn’t understand, is that you should answer whether repeatedly applying the function will evolve to 1 or 4. The question is not whether there is a 1 or 4 within the digits.

Comment: Well.. for some reason I though Stream.of(int) worked, now it seems obvious that it wouldn't work. Is this the correct way of making a Stream of Integers? `Stream.of(String.valueOf(Math.round( Math.pow(x, 2))).toCharArray()).mapToInt(num -> Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(num)))` Tbh seems dirty to me, I think there might be a better way :)

Comment: `Stream.of(String.valueOf(Math.round( Math.pow(x, 2))).toCharArray())` still doesn’t work; it creates a stream with the array as its only element. If you want to stream over a string’s characters, just use `chars()`, i.e. `String.valueOf(x * x) .chars() .map(ch -> ch - '0') .sum()`. However, the loop of the answer which doesn’t go the character detour, is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What takes time is writing to standard output, so if you write the result to standard output for each test case, that will increase the overall time significantly.

You can use `StringBuilder` and append to it the result of each test case. Then after you have handled all the test cases, print out the entire contents of the `StringBuilder`.

Also, I think you misunderstood the question. Your code checks whether the sum of the digits of the square of the test case number (i.e. the result of function *F(N)*) **contains** a 1 (one) or a 4. As I understand it, you need to check whether the result of *F(N)* **is** 1 or 4.

Here is my solution which was accepted on *hackerearth*, i.e. it produced the correct results in an acceptable time.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MoodyNumbers {

    private static boolean is1or4(int x) {
        boolean result = x == 1 || x == 4;
        if (!result) {
            int newX = sumDigits((long) x * x);
            if (newX == 1 || newX == 4) {
                return true;
            }
            if (newX == 9 || newX == 16) {
                return false;
            }
            result = is1or4(newX);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int sumDigits(long x) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (x >= 10) {
            sum += x % 10;
            x /= 10;
        }
        sum += x;
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfTestCases = stdin.nextInt();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(numberOfTestCases * 4);
        String newLine = System.lineSeparator();
        while (numberOfTestCases-- > 0) {
            int n = stdin.nextInt();
            sb.append((is1or4(n) ? "YES" : "NO"));
            sb.append(newLine);
        }
        System.out.print(sb);
    }
}
```

If the result of *F(N)* is either 9 or 16, that creates an endless loop. *F(9)* returns 9. *F(16)* returns 13 and *F(13)* returns 16 which also creates an endless loop. Hence for any number for which *F(N)* eventually returns either 9 or 16, the result is `NO`.